# Как добавлять и размещать элементы в JavaFx правильно?

Tags: javafx, gui

Делаю первое GUI и выбрал JavaFX. Делаю JavaFX проект в IntelliJ IDEA. Добавил кнопку в simple.fxml (методы добавления кнопок прямо в Main не сработали) и о чудо, кнопка есть! Но как её расположить, скажем в левом нижнем углу без "Сцен билдер", а то это как phhdevilstudio, а он для школоты.

---

Main:

```
package ru.timofeheus.fx.test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("\u0422\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0435 \u0413\u0423\u0418");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 555, 355));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<GridPane fx:controller="ru.timofeheus.fx.test.controller.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <Button text="Тыкни меня!!!"/>
</GridPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем усложнять себе жизнь и ограничивать себя в инструментах?
Мы же молоток на камень не меняем?
Все расположение задается с помощью сеттеров координат каждого компонента. Но это все мелочи, так как для действительно качественного GUI, нужно использовать обертки, относительное положение, и.т.д. И с нуля набирать опыт это просто сущий ад. 
Мой совет, освойте scenebuilder, научитесь там делать качественный GUI, а потом уже подсматривая в fxml код, смотреть как все устроено. И пытаться делать уже без "сцен билдера". 
На заметку: создание компонентов а тем более их редактирование и позиционирование именно кодом java, просто ужасно засоряет проект, и использовать это лучше только в случае крайней необходимости.

Comment: Хорошо, но тогда зачем делать `primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 555, 355));`, если в сцен билдере можно создать какой то пеин? И вообще, может мне кинет кто сурсы? Я ничё не понимаю...

Comment: Правильно, незачем. 
Можно просто создать какой то пеин, добавить его через фксмл загрузчик:
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("..."));
и назначить как сцену 
Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();

Comment: Ничего не понимаю. Вот например я в вопросе выложил Main и я не понимаю, зачем делать сцену, если в сцен билдере я уже сделал пеин? Приведите, пожалуйста, готовый код с объяснениями для новичков как я) Я вообще не понимаю этот JavaFX

Comment: пеин, это всего лишь fxml документ, тебе нужно создать объект  родительского окна, в который ты и передаешь fxml,
root это и будет тот пеин(род.окно)
Далее нужно создать объект самой сцены scene, в конструктор сцены передается уже родительское окно
А дальше просто что бы все это отображалось нужно в primaryStage задать эту сцену, и просто начать отображение методом show()

Comment: в чем вообще проблема? не добавляется кнопка, или не отображается окно?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74026/discussion-between-timoha-timohavich-and-bogdan-bida).

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае уместен `AnchorPane`:

`// leftdown.fxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <Button text="Button" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="12.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="12.0"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

`// LeftDown.java:`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LeftDown extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("leftdown.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```